# CircleCI: how to force queue the builds

Tags: git, firebase, circleci

I am using Circle CI to deploy my SPA site to Firebase using 
`firebase deploy`.
I have a paid plan of Circle CI with 2 containers.

[image]
When I push the codes to GitHub 2 times sequently, 1 minute after the last commit, Circle CI builds are competing each other.(`#696` and `#695` are running at the same time when I push #696 after shortly after #695).
As `#695` is deploying Firebase Cloud Functions, `#696` fails with the message: `functions: HTTP Error: 400, An operation on function onInitiativeRemoved in region us-central1 in project init-dev-a7563 is already in progress. Please try again later.`

My goal is to run 2 containers at the same time only in the different branches: master and other.
I want to run only 1 container in the same branch and other builds should be queued in the same branch.

In a word, I'd like to make `#696` built after `#695`

Answer (score 1):

There's two things you might want to do:

1. Only deploy the `default`/`master` branch.
2. Turn on the `Auto-cancel redundant builds` setting.

---

You can't choose to only run certain branches in certain containers within CircleCI. You can do something like phd's answer but technically those builds are still running, then dying out early.

With the setting I mentioned, queued and running builds will be cancelled when a new commit is pushed. Here's the setting description:

> With the exception of your default branch, we will automatically cancel any queued or running builds on a branch when a newer build is triggered on that same branch. This feature will only apply to builds triggered by pushes to GitHub.

The setting can be found at: `Settings > Build Settings > Advanced Settings`.

- Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply check the current container number and the current branch:

```
test:
  override:
    - ?
        case $CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX in
            0) if [ `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` = master ]; then make master-test; fi ;;
            1) if [ `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` != master ]; then make other-test; fi ;;
        esac
      :
        parallel: true
```

Run tests for master in container number 0 and tests for non-master branch(es) in container number 1.